# React Native and initial data storage when app is installed

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native, but I'm investigating and trying things out while building a small sample mobile app. I have some working app, but here is the question:

Imagine my app is having some initial data, a lot of text data or json formatted information. How do I manage that data? If we are looking for websites, all that kind of data can be stored in databases, but how about an app?

How to have the data available when someone installs an app? What are the best practices?

I've read about AsyncStorage / Realm / SQLLite, is this the way to go? But it seems more like saving data when the app is being used, but what about the initial data? For example, if I have a language study app: and it has table with words and the translations ... so I need to have all that information inside the database on the moment the app is launched for the first time.

And how to create that kind of database?

Answer (score 0):

> If we are looking for websites, all that kind of data can be stored in databases, but how about an app?

On a website, these data are fetched from a backend server. You can do something similar where you make an API call to a backend server which returns the data you want to show on the app, but this will involve a use of a backend API.

You can also store the data on something like AsyncStorage. You'll just have to hardcode the initial data and load/set the data onto AsyncStorage when the app first launches.

Comment: is there no way, to having like a database defined with values on installation of an app?

Comment: You do have to initialize the database with the data you want. I don't think you can pre configure the database with all the values with the app's build. Maybe you can check how to create offline-first apps using React Native. You might find information about how best to initialize and setup a database and which database is best for this.